How to Add OAuth2 to My JWT Authentication Project in Spring Boot
I'm currently working on a Spring Boot project for a real estate listing application where I've implemented JWT authentication. I followed a YouTube tutorial to learn how to create the authentication mechanism using JWT, and I added a few customizations to understand the concepts better. Now, I want to extend this project by integrating OAuth2 for additional security and flexibility.
This is my User Entity
package com.marvi.realestatelisting.Entity;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String email;
    private String password;
    private String role;

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return email;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}

This is my Security Configuration
package com.marvi.realestatelisting.Config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.AbstractHttpConfigurer;
import org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter;

import com.marvi.realestatelisting.Service.UserService;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private JWTAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
            .authorizeHttpRequests(request -> request
                .requestMatchers("/auth/**", "/public/**", "/uploads/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/agent/**").hasAuthority("AGENT")
                .requestMatchers("/user/**").hasAuthority("USER")
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
            .sessionManagement(manager -> manager.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
            .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
            .addFilterBefore(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return httpSecurity.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider provider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        provider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
        provider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return provider;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration) throws Exception {
        return authenticationConfiguration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}

This my JWT Authentication Filter:
package com.marvi.realestatelisting.Config;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetailsSource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import com.marvi.realestatelisting.Service.JwtUtils;
import com.marvi.realestatelisting.Service.UserService;

import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

@Component
public class JWTAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtUtils jwtUtils;

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
        final String jwtToken;
        final String userEmail;

        if (authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        jwtToken = authHeader.substring(7);
        userEmail = jwtUtils.extractUsername(jwtToken);

        if (userEmail != null && SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() == null) {
            UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(userEmail);

            if (jwtUtils.isTokenValid(jwtToken, userDetails)) {
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
                authToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authToken);
            }
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}

I want to add OAuth2 support to this existing JWT setup to enable social logins and OAuth2 flows. The YouTube tutorial I followed didn't cover OAuth2 integration. Could someone help me figure out how to add OAuth2 to this project?

I have to say it is tough to tell every detail in a comment, you mentioned that you want to use both JWT and oauth2, JWT is just a tokenEnhancer for oauth2, you have to build up an oauth2 server and your own client first, and spring security does not support oauth2, you must use spring security oauth2 instead.

My bet is that you started with JWTs because your frontend is a SPA (Angular, React, Vue, etc.) or a mobile app. The bad news is that you should not send tokens to a frontend running remotely: this annihilates the control over users' sessions and exposes to several security vulnerabilities. The good news is that I wrote a detailed tutorial with an alternate solution: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2
